# RestTemplate custom Jackson JSON deserializer

Tags: java, json, jackson, resttemplate

I get a JSON response that looks like this:

[
  {
    "name": "This"
  },
  {
    "name": "That"
  }
]

I would rather not create a POJO (to receive an array of POJOs) for this but rather just get a String array with the values. So how can I instruct Jackson to do this and then use it together with RestTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

Just specify List as target Class, jackson will use List and Map to write equivalent of JSONArrays and JSONObjects

```
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper ();
    try
    {
        final List readValue = mapper.readValue ("[{ 'name': 'This' }, { 'name': 'That' }]".replace ('\'', '"'), List.class);
        //readValue is a list of Map
    }
    catch (final IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<List<HashMap<String, String>>> typeRef = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<HashMap<String, String>>>() {};
ResponseEntity<List<HashMap<String, String>>> response = new RestTemplate().exchange(youUrl, HttpMethod.GET, null, typeRef);
```